# Multiple OS's already installed - Only have Windows 7

Tags: boot, partitioning, windows, 13.10

I installed Ubuntu 13.10 to my USB drive and i reboot my computer and choose boot from USB drive and all is fine and dandy. I click install, connect to wifi, and then when you are prompted to select either delete all other OS, create custom partition, or go along with a standard installation - my computer does not give me the option for a standard and also states that I have multiple OS's installed.

I just did a full reset on my computer. Wiped the hard drive, reset all computer settings and went straight to downloading ubuntu.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: How do I get it so I can dual boot

Answer (score 0):

It may be that you wiped the partitions but not the MBR. If you are planning to use the whole drive just for Ubuntu, then just choose the option to delete all other OS.

If you are planning to dual boot, you should set up Windows first. If you are still able to, recover Windows to the computer from the recovery partition. Then boot into Windows and install Ubuntu using Wubi.

Comment: I am wanting to dual boot so I want to keep windows. How can I delete the MBR? I do not have a windows disk, I just have the recovery partition on the hard drive.

Comment: In that case don't format the whole drive or delete the MBR. Recover Windows to the computer first. Then boot into windows and install Ubuntu from within Windows using Wubi.